# Find minimal distance between point and three dimensional graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=4x^2+y^2$, such that $X:=\{(x, y, f(x, y)): x, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.
I now want to find the point(s) $\in X$ for which the distance to $(0,0,4)$ is minimal. I tried working with the second derivative as well as the fact that $f$ is the $z$ coordinate of $X$, but I have been stuck in finding the minimum distance.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Make a function $g(x,y)$ that is the distance squared (equivalent problem). Then use the standard method for evaluating critical points with two inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
The problem can be model as

Minimize: $d^2=x^2+y^2+(z-4)^2$

Conditioned to: $4x^2+y^2-z=0$.

Comment: To solve classically ones uses the technique of Lagrange's Multipliers from multivariable calculus.

Comment: I am trying the approach with Langrange's multiplies but I get $L_x= 2x-8\lambda x = 0$ which results in $x= 4 \lambda x$. How can I solve this without dividing by zero? @janmarqz

Comment: why do you want to divide by zero?

Comment: How can I solve the formula the Langrange multiplier formula for x without making sure I do not dive by zero, because for example $4\lambda= x/x = 1$. Maybe I am misunderstanding the Langrange multiplier approach, because I haven't used it before.

Comment: The Lagrange's method gives you three equations: $$2x=\lambda 8x,$$ $$2y=\lambda 2y,$$ and $$2(z-4)=-\lambda.$$ A solution is $\lambda=0$ and then $z=4$ and $x=\pm1$. So the points $(1,0,4)^{\top}$ and $(-1,0,4)^{\top}$  are in the "paraboloid" $4x^2+y^2=z$ close to the point $(0,0,4)^{\top}$. A simple plot of everything should serve to see that clearly.

Comment: Thank you a lot now it's very clear .(the plot was a good tip)